# Can't plot anything with matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

Whenever I try to plot something with matplotlib, I get the following error:

```
 File "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2018, in __init__

baseName = os.path.basename(sys.argv[0])
builtins.IndexError: list index out of range
```

For example, i've tried the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
N = 50
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
colors = np.random.rand(N)
area = np.pi * (15 * np.random.rand(N))**2  # 0 to 15 point radii


plt.scatter(x, y, s=area, c=colors, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

I have the latest version of matplotlib, please help.

Thank you

Comment: What IDE, if any, are you using?

Comment: I was using Wing, now I've tried Sublime and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Okay. I suspect it was an issue with the Wing installation (I've never used it). You were getting an error related to Tcl/Tk, which is used for the GUI in some Python applications. You could try reinstalling Wing, or reinstalling Tcl/Tk, but I'm not sure if you want to go down that path at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import numpy.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
N = 50
x = np.random.rand(N)
y = np.random.rand(N)
colors = np.random.rand(N)
area = np.pi * (15 * np.random.rand(N))**2  # 0 to 15 point radii


plt.scatter(x, y, s=area, c=colors, alpha=0.5)
plt.show()
```

Comment: sorry, forgot to copy it into the question, however it is not the issue